# Refactoring a nested loop into Java 8 streams collecting the outer objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a loop which does what I want - it adds objects of type `A` to the `results` list:

```
ArrayList<A> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (A a: listOfA) {
  for (B b : a.getListOfB()) {
    if ("myString".equals(b.getMyString())) {
      results.add(a);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to refactor my code using Java 8 streams and I came up with this solution I'm stuck with because it collects objects of type `B` instead of `A` - `List<A> results = ...` is obviously wrong:

```
List<A> results = listOfA.stream()
  .flatMap(a -> a.getListOfB().stream())
  .filter(b -> "myString".equals(b.getMyString()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I collect a list of type `A` using Java 8 streams?

---

I found many results here in SO looking for [[java]  nested foreach stream](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20%20nested%20foreach%20stream&searchOn=3) but I couldn't find anything that suits my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `flatMap` here. Just apply a `filter` on the `Stream<A>`.

```
List<A> results = 
    listOfA.stream()
           .filter(a -> a.getListOfB()
                         .stream()
                         .anyMatch(b -> "myString".equals(b.getMyString())))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming you don't want to add an instance of `A` multiple times to the `List` if it has multiple `B` instances that match `"myString"`.

Comment: I just learned you can't be sure that Collectors.toList() returns an ArrayList, you have to use 'Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`  to be sure...

Comment: @Turo unless you don't care about the List implementation that you'll get.

Comment: In the original code results is an ArrayList. If some modifying is done afterwards, the new code isn't safe, since it could be an imutable List you get, that's all I wanted to say :-)

Comment: @Turo But the OP's streams attempt (`List<A> results = listOfA.stream()...`) was to create a `List<A>`, not `ArrayList<A>`, so I assumed it doesn't matter.